# why when I print a string more than once it deletes some random characters?

Tags: assembly, x86

when I'm printing a string in my code with those lines:

```
    mov dl, 25   ;J
    mov dh, 21    ;I
    mov bh, 0     ;Display page 0
    mov ah, 02h   ;SetCursor
    int 10h
    mov dx, offset message5
    mov ah, 09h   ;DispayString
    int 21h
```

then run some other stuff (and I don't touch the var 'message5'), and then when I rerun those exact same lines (after I switch to text mode and graphic mode to set the screen)
it prints the message without some characters. even tho there are other messages that work fine.
for example for this message

```
message5 db 'hello',10,13,'$'
```

the second time I print it, it prints "h llo" without the 'e'.
Is there a way to know why it happens?

Comment: Something is probably overwriting the `e` in hello with something else.  Use a debugger and try setting a hardware watchpoint on that memory location to see who is writing to it.

Comment: how can I set a hardware watchpoint? I do have the debugger

Comment: Use the debugger's hardware watchpoint command.  Usually `watch` if you're using a gdb or adb derived debugger.